# Can't navigate user to MainPage.xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

This is a really weird situation I'm in here. Lets, for the sake of simplicity say that I have 3 pages. '**MainPage.xaml**', '**SeconPage.xaml**' and '**ThirdPage.xaml**'. I'm trying to navigate to 'MainPage.xaml' from 'ThirdPage.xaml' using the following code:

```
// Forward user to MainPage                        
try
{
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}
catch (Exception ete)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error when navigating: " + ete.ToString());
}
```

This for some unknown reason, doesn't work... No error gets thrown, nothing. It simply does nothing. And this code does get executed I've confirmed with a bunch of MessageBox calls around it.

When I try and do the exact same with the exact same code from 'SecondPage.xaml'. Everything works perfectly... I have no idea on how to trouble shoot this, especially if no error messages are presented. Any help would really be appreciated!

**EDIT**
(ThirdPage.xaml.cs as requested by @AmanKhandelwal)

```
public partial class ThirdPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public ThirdPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnForgotPin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Clear out entire cache
        DataCache myCache = new DataCache();
        myCache.deleteEntireCache();

        // Forward user to login screen                        
        try
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }
        catch (Exception ete)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error when navigating: " + ete.ToString());
        }

    }

    protected override void OnBackKeyPress(CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        /* When back button is pressed on this page the app has to close,
         * the user is not allowed to interact with the app without providing
         * the authentication pin.
         */
        throw new ExitException();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);

        MessageBox.Show("Hitting OnNavigatedFrom");
    }
}
```

Comment: I really dont know what the problem is. but you try Making an OnNavigatedFrom event in ThirdPage.xaml and an OnNavigatedTo in MainPage.xaml.this is Just a step to check/debug whether the navigation is properly getting performed or not.

Comment: is your main page in some folder or its in main directory ?

Comment: Just to ensure - do SecondPage and ThirdPage differ (anything) or it's just a copy with different name? And to SecondPage and ThirdPage you Navigate from Main or to Third from Second? I assume they are in the same directory - yes?

Comment: @SandeepChauhan - In the main directory, I also thought it's a path error. But it's not.

Comment: @Romasz - SecondPage and ThirdPage is exactly the same, and all of them are in the same directory yes

Comment: @AmanKhandelwal - So i've added the onNavigatedFrom and onNavigatedTo functions... None of them are getting executed... What could this mean?

Comment: @Relborg-This is very weird problem.But can I know ur functionality.I mean if you are navigating from MainPage to secondPage and MainPage to thirdPage,then you can use NavigationService.GoBack()

Comment: if onNavigatedFrom is not getting executed then ThirdPage.xaml is in problems. But if you are saying that SecondPage and ThirdPage are exactly the same then I would like to know whats happening in ThirdPage.xaml.cs.

Comment: @AmanKhandelwal - I'll update my question with some more code. It's also worth mentioning that 'ThirdPage.xaml' CAN navigate to other pages I have, e.g. 'ThirdPage' can Forward to 'SeconPage'.. but just not MainPage

Comment: @AmanKhandelwal How about this little hack: I create another page 'FourthPage'. I then navigate from ThirdPage to FourthPage and as soon as I hit FourthPage I navigate to MainPage?

Comment: Saw the edits, I dont know what a DataChache does, But I think if it clears some cache stuff then this could also be the problem. Remove that part and see. And that FourthPage trick is really clever of you.

Comment: @AmanKhandelwal This basically just clears everything in isolatedStorage. I'll try that fourthPage thing. Really bad that I have to resort to this haha.

Comment: One more way. NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(string.Format("/MainPage.xaml?Refresh=true&random={0}", Guid.NewGuid()), UriKind.Relative)); this navigates to the same page again. Using this with one boolean flag could prevent you from making your hands dirty making a fourthPage.:)

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that you never reached the `ThirdPage.xaml` and that you are still on `SecondPage.xaml`?

Comment: Okay so here's the solution that worked for me (Sorry @AmanKhandelwal , none of your suggestions worked). So what I did, was make an exact copy of MainPage.xaml and called it MainPage2.xaml. I then forwarded the user to MainPage2 which worked. From a developers perspective - so bad, from a user's perspective - they won't notice.

Comment: hahaha A soultion that one could never think of. @Relborg

Comment: Did you tried to make "Clean Solution" and rebuild it?

Answer (score 0):

well it seems like you are using the navigator in the wrong way the correct syntex is

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/[name_of_your_project];component/[page_name.xaml]", UriKind.Relative));
```

put this after doing changes as described.